# Ament_cmake - recommended way to link a library doesn't work?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to pull in the Eigen3 library as a dependency of my library on Dashing (latest patch release, on Ubuntu), but I'm not sure the "most correct" way to do this.

This does not build, but is what [I thought was the recommendation](https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Tutorials/Ament-CMake-Documentation/#adding-dependencies):

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
ament_target_dependencies(sba Eigen3)
```

It fails with something like:

```
--- stderr: sparse_bundle_adjustment                                                                               
In file included from /home/dan/ros2_ws/src/sparse_bundle_adjustment/src/sba.cpp:39:0:
/home/dan/ros2_ws/src/sparse_bundle_adjustment/include/sparse_bundle_adjustment/sba.h:48:10: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
 #include <Eigen/Core>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sba.dir/src/sba.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/sba.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This builds, and is listed as the way to do it up to ROS Crystal, with caveats:

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(sba Eigen3::Eigen)
```

This builds, is not in the docs, and I know is terrible practice:

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
target_include_directories(sba PRIVATE ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_definitions(sba PRIVATE ${EIGEN3_DEFINITIONS})
```

Entire CMakeLists for context:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(sparse_bundle_adjustment)

if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)

add_library(sba
  src/sba.cpp src/spa.cpp src/spa2d.cpp src/csparse.cpp src/proj.cpp src/node.cpp src/sba_file_io.cpp)

target_include_directories(sba
  PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)

# this does not build
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
ament_target_dependencies(sba Eigen3)

## this builds
#find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
#target_link_libraries(sba Eigen3::Eigen)

## this builds
#find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
#target_include_directories(sba PUBLIC ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#target_compile_definitions(sba PUBLIC ${EIGEN3_DEFINITIONS})


target_compile_definitions(sba
  PRIVATE SBA_CHOLMOD
  )

ament_export_interfaces(export_sba HAS_LIBRARY_TARGET)
ament_export_dependencies(Eigen3)

target_link_libraries(sba blas lapack cholmod cxsparse)

install(DIRECTORY include/
        DESTINATION include/)

install(
  TARGETS sba
  EXPORT export_sba
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)
ament_package()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330921/ament_cmake---recommended-way-to-link-a-library-doesn%27t-work?/) by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2019-08-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `Eigen3Config.cmake` file shipped with Ubuntu Bionic is missing some standard CMake variables. Use the package `eigen3_cmake_module` to workaround this. This package is available in Dashing. It looks like that documentation should be updated to use a different example.

`eigen3_cmake_module` instructions are in its README: https://github.com/ros2/eigen3_cmake_module#eigen3_cmake_module

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on 2019-08-16**:
Thank you! I thought I was going crazy :-)